# Evaluate the impact of upgrade SAPUI5 libraries

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am an SAP Fiori developer and have been reading some days about the best way for planning an upgrade with the maximum level of guarantees to avoid unexpected errors.

I know that for evaluating the impact of changes in our applications, I have to read “What's New” and do an accurate read and analysis of "Changelog."

My idea is to create a human step by step procedure, and if we do all the steps the impact will be evaluated with a very high percentage of coverage. Because I have assumed that there isn’t an automatic process for evaluating that, is it true?

We have a table with which controls and components are in every application and view/controller for evaluating the “direct” impact of upgrades.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg3o5.png)

My doubt is how I can be sure about if a fix could generate a wrong behavior. I will explain it with an example: “1.71.21 -  [FIX] format/NumberFormat: parse special values ‘00000’”, analyzing it, I know that in sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable is using “Number format” for displaying the num. records in the header title but with the API is impossible to have the knowledge. This is only an example but reading the "Changelog," a lot of doubts like this appear and are also and more complicated to associate with.

To give you more info, I have thought to use the CDN with the new version, but this could position us in a scenario where we should do manual testing of everything and look for errors, warnings, and wrong behavior.

How did you analyze an upgrade before doing it, and how did you avoid doing human testing of everything, with the risk of forgetting things? Are you using some tool?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the library carries a comparable risk of introducing defects as regular development. Therefore, conventional quality assurance guidelines will apply to an upgrade: setting up and doing your tests manually or automatically.